# Get a list of savepoints in MySQL InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, savepoints

How do I get a list of savepoints in InnoDB? I need it because in my database I'm running a function which may or may not have made a number of savepoints.

Comment: @Solarflare http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/savepoint.html

Comment: Hmm, sorry, my question was unprecise: a savepoint is only relevant for the current function and for the current transaction. If a function had created a savepoint, or the transaction ended, it is gone now.

Comment: Give us the bigger picture of what you are trying to accomplish.